# How to add an existing cube into an SSAS project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssas, ssms

I need to add a new version of a Cube in an existing SSAS database.  I've created the new Cube by using Management Studio to script the old Cube to a screen, changed the ID's to the new ID, and executing the script.

So now the new Cube exists in the database.

I want to put the new cube into my existing Visual Studio project.  Can I import a cube from a database (as opposed to the whole database)?  Can I import the script logic that is created by Management Studio?

If neither of these things, what is the best way for me to import this new cube into the project?

Thanks,  --sw

ps--all versions are the newest (e.g., Visual Studio 2012, SSAS 2012, and so on).  --sw

Answer (score 0):

I would start from a Visual Studio Project, which is the "source code" for SSAS.  If you dont have this already you can use Visual Studio to Import from the server, while creating a new Project.

Then in Visual Studio I would copy and paste the Cube object, and work from there.